# Spookyjs error with Child terminated with non-zero exit code 3221225477

Tags: node.js, casperjs, spookyjs

all

I can run spookyjs program without a problem. 
However, if it runs over long period of time, e.g. 24 hours or 48 hours, continuously the program stops with this message. Anyone got a clue for this error?
It could be other environment issue as spookyjs log seems fine.

**{ [Error: Child terminated with non-zero exit code 3221225477] 
details: { code: 3221225477, signal: null } }**

Setting:

```
var spooky = new Spooky({
    child: {
        transport: 'http'
    },
    casper: {
        logLevel: 'debug', 
        verbose: true,
        "ssl-protocol": "any", //added for phantomjs ssl-protocol error
         clientScripts:  [
        '../lib/jquery-2.2.3.min.js',
        ]
    },
child: {
    port: 10010,
    bufferSize: 32 * 1024 // 32KB
    }     
}
```

...

My working environments:

1. node: v0.12.4
2. casperjs: 1.1.0-beta5
3. phantomjs: 1.9.7
4. npm: 2.10.1
5. os: windows 10